# Join Queries with parameter filter on second query SSMS

Tags: sql, oracle10g, ssrs-2008, sql-server-2008

I have two tables: EQUIPMENT and WORKORDERS. 
EQUIPMENT returns the count of Equipment against a particular depot by the type of Equipment:

```
MAINTDEPOT EQUIPCOUNT EQUIPTYPE
1          44         MC
2          20         MC
3          5          MC
1          20         FS
2          3          FS
3          10         FS
```

...and so on. These counts rarely change unless a new bit of kit is put in.

I need to join a count of WORKORDERS to this table, but the work orders have a COSTCENTRE of either A B or E. This is so that I can generate a percentage of equipment with workorders.

I've joined the tables, but when I add a parameter filter to the WORKORDERS COSTCENTRE column the Count of EQUIPMENT changes, and I need it to stay the same.

I'm guessing I need to use subqueries to ensure that the left subquery remains static whilst the filter only changes the right hand one. Does anyone have any idea how I do this?

Here's my current query:

```
SELECT  E.E_MAINTDEPOT, E.E_EQUIPCOUNT, C.Category, E.MYORDER, E.W_WORKCOUNT, 
        E.E_NOWO, E.W_HRS, E.E_QA, E.E_EGI, E.E_CLASS, 
        ISNULL(ROUND(CAST(E.E_NOWO AS Float) / 
                     CAST(E.E_EQUIPCOUNT AS Float) * 100, 2), 100) AS RESULT, 
        SUBSTRING(E.E_CLASS, 1, 1) AS EM_CLASS
FROM (
  SELECT  T.E_MAINTDEPOT, COUNT(T.EQUIP_NO) AS E_EQUIPCOUNT, 
          SUM(C.W_WORKCOUNT) AS W_WORKCOUNT, 
          COUNT(T.EQUIP_NO) - SUM(C.W_WORKCOUNT) AS E_NOWO, T.MYORDER, 
          T.E_QA, T.E_EGI, T.E_CLASS, SUM(C.W_HRS) AS W_HRS
  FROM     EQDType AS T 
  FULL OUTER JOIN EquipWOCount AS C 
    ON T.EQUIP_NO = C.EQUIP_NO
  GROUP BY T.MYORDER, T.E_MAINTDEPOT, T.E_QA, T.E_EGI, T.E_CLASS, C.W_FUNCTION
) AS E 
INNER JOIN EQDCategory AS C 
  ON E.MYORDER = C.Myorder 
ORDER BY E.MYORDER, E.E_MAINTDEPOT
```

Thank you

Comment: Could you add your current query and some sample data to execute it against to demonstrate what is not working? I find the current description a little too vague to answer with a concrete solution.

Comment: Sure - I've added my current query on. Basically the total count of EQUIPMENT doesn't change, only the total count of Work Orders does, depending on which cost centre that work order has.